# what is the algorithm used in pandas.query() to let this function so fast?

Tags: python, pandas, select

I am trying to develop a data operating framework with pure Python called DaPy(http://www.github.com/jacksonwuxs/dapy) to improve my skills. I am wondering that why query function in pandas is so fast?

Of course I know pandas is implemented by C, but I don't believe it is the only reason. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

this is the code what I used

```
df.query('pm25 >= 500')
df[df['pm25'] >500]
```

I am very grateful some answers like: "binary search is used in pandas query function to match the exactely record" or "I know a website which best illustrates the detail of query function"

Comment: Pandas is open source, have you checked the source code? https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/core/frame.py#L3012-L3100

Comment: What makes you think it is "so fast"? On a 10,000-line dataframe of random numbers, the second statement runs 3 times faster than the first.

Comment: I found that after the DataFrame evaluate the statemet, the calling chain goes as following  ```pandas.core.indexing._LocationIndexer```-> ```pandas.core.generic.NDFrame._take()```->```pandas.core.internals.BlockManager.take()```->```pandas.core.internals.make_block()```

Comment: @alec_djinn go through the above calling chain, it use the  the numpy.ndarray.__getitem__ or __getslice__ functions  to  select the data. So the problem changes to why numpy  can  select the data by index so fast?

Comment: @DYZ well in this problem, I am not comparing the efficiency between DataFrame.__getitem__ and DataFrame.query. In fact, I want to know why it is faster than  we implement the similar structure by comparing the values row  by row.